# How can I color a <li> or <a> element form a menu when the element is refering to a specific page?

Tags: css, styling

I want a list item to have a specific color when the page is being showed on screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7tH7.png)
I´m on the "experiencia" page so I want the

Experiencia

to be colored in other color

Answer (score -1):

Add this code into your stylesheet, it will work perfectly

```css
li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: pink !important;
}
```